# SQL Group_concat not get all data

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have 2 table and second table use relationship

```
table1
id   name
---------
1    alpha
2    beta

table2
id   name  relation
-------------------
1    2015    2
2    2016    2
3    2017    2
4    2018    2
```

I want to see

```
name   data
-------------------------
beta   2015,2016,2017,2018
alpha  NULL
```

I tried the following sql query but the output is not what I wanted

I use:

```
SELECT 
    t1.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t2.relation = t1.id
```

Output:

```
alpha 2015,2016,2017,2018
```

Alpha doesn't get any value in the other related tablature. the values in the output belong to the beta.

Comment: **G**ROUP_CONCAT...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ',')
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.relation = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

In most databases (and recent versions of MySQL), your query would fail.  It is an aggregation query (because of the `GROUP_CONCAT()`).  But, `t1.name` is not an argument to an aggregation function and it is not a `GROUP BY` key.

MySQL does allow this type of query.  It returns exactly one row.  The value of `t1.name` on the one row in the result set comes from an arbitrary row.

Answer (score 0):

No FKs for fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1    (`id` int, `name` varchar(5)) ;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'alpha'),
    (2, 'beta')
;


CREATE TABLE Table2    (`id` int, `name` int, `relation` int);

INSERT INTO Table2
    (`id`, `name`, `relation`)
VALUES
    (1, 2015, 2),
    (2, 2016, 2),
    (3, 2017, 2),
    (4, 2018, 2)
;
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    t1.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ',') -- missing an AS .... => ugly name from fiddle
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
    ON t2.relation = t1.id
group by t1.name
```

Output:

```
name    GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name SEPARATOR ',')
alpha   (null)
beta    2017,2018,2015,2016
```